# Extracting correlated data

Tags: machine-learning

Lets say I have a dataset like this image here https://i.stack.imgur.com/z5TPh.jpg. The top figure is a histogram of the underlying data points which tend to be distributed vertically, horizontal, and at some positive slope - all of which originating from various, separated points.

I am specifically interested in extracting data that is distributed at an **angle** from a given central point (roughly 45 degrees in this specific case). I am not super knowledgeable in the specifics of machine learning algorithms, rather I would like some advice on what direction to head in attempting to solve this problem.

Answer (score 0):

If you are interested in finding the locations of the different lines formed by data points along a specific axis, histograms might be a way to go. As you can see in your example plots, you simply have to find the peaks in the histogram distributions (have a look at [peak finding](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/reference/signal.html#peak-finding) in `scipy.signal` for that purpose).

In order to find vertical and diagonal lines, you can simply create histograms along a different feature axis, or linear combinations thereof. This should be trivial if the diagonal lines (or all of them really) are parallel. If they are not parallel, a different approach might be better.